# On the orthogonality of the spin operator in a $z$-basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

After, in the $S_z$-basis $|S_{z,\pm}\rangle$ denoted by $|\pm\rangle$ and in units $\frac{\hbar}{2}$, finding the spin operator in a general direction $\vec{n} = (\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$:

$$\hat{\vec{S}}\cdot\vec{n} = \sin\theta\cos\phi\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} + \sin\theta\sin\phi\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -i\\
i & 0
\end{bmatrix} + \cos\theta\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & e^{-i\phi}\sin\theta\\
e^{i\phi} \sin\theta & -\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$
I find the eigenvectors
$$|S_{\vec{n},+}\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta/2\\
e^{i\phi}\sin\theta/2
\end{bmatrix}\text{   and   }|S_{\vec{n},-}\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta/2\\
-e^{i\phi}\cos\theta/2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now it is normally quite easy to see that these should be orthogonal but for some reason I just don't get $\langle S_{\vec{n},+}|S_{\vec{n},-}\rangle$ to equal zero:
$$\langle S_{\vec{n},+}|S_{\vec{n},-}\rangle = \cos\frac\theta2 \sin\frac\theta2\left(1-e^{2i\phi}\right)$$
what is going wrong? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the complex conjugate when you go from bra to ket. So $e^{i \phi} \to e^{-i \phi}$ and the bracket is $(1-1)=0$